# Laravel 5.5 login form on every page, refresh instead of redirect

Tags: php, authentication, redirect, laravel-5

For a web project that requires a login/register system and lot of CRUD operations, I choose to learn Laravel. I have some experience from school with MVC .NET and Spring and while there are a lot of similarities, some things are a little bit different... The requirement of this project is that it has a login form on every page when not logged in (guest). That form changes to "the profile" of the user when logged in (auth). The problem I'm having is that when I log in and try to redirect using the middleware RedirectIfAuthenticated, I come in an infinite loop of redirects for some reason. Is there a solution to create a login form on every page, and instead of redirecting to another view, just refresh the page and set the correct values using Blade's templating engine?
I've created the base with the `php artisan make:auth` command, and made some changes myself. I'll post snippets of what I have with the according class.

To give an idea how it's gonna look & why there need to be a form on every page: (btw I'm putting it in the footer in *layouts/app.blade.php*.
[image: example image]

Routes/web.php:
I unraffeld the Facade Auth::routes() to this so I can make changes. I left login temporarly but it should be gone when I got my things working. The bottom 2 comments I ommitted.

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('teams', 'HomeController@teams')->name('teams');
Route::get('schedules', 'HomeController@schedules')->name('schedules');
Route::get('tables', 'HomeController@tables')->name('tables');
Route::get('rules', 'HomeController@rules')->name('rules');

Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

// Registration Routes...

// Password Reset Routes...
```

HomeController.php

Here I'm doubting the configuration in the constructor should it be 'guest' or 'auth' as middleware?

```
    class HomeController extends Controller
    {
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Show the homepage.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }

    //other pages omitted
    }
```

LoginController.php (no difference with artisan auth):

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

RedirectIfAuthenticated.php:

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

App.blade.php:

```
@if (Auth::guest())

    //login form omitted ...

@else

   <!-- TODO: check for role & display correct nav -->
   <h2>Logged in!</h2>

  <form id="logout-form" action="{{ url('/logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
      {{ csrf_field() }}
  </form>
 @endif
```

Tell me if you need more info.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `web.php` routes file you declared the home route twice:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

I'd change that to:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Then in your `LoginController` you'll need to update the `$redirectTo` to reflect that change. So:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/';
```

Same for your `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware:

```
if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Last but not least, your `HomeController` middleware is incorrect. `guest` is for routes that are only accessible when unauthenticated, such as login, register or forget password. But since you want the routes from your `HomeController` to only be accessible by authenticated users, then you'd have to change the middleware to `auth`:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Comment: That seems to work. Only thing is that when I click the logout link, it logs out as expected, but redirects to /login. Any idea where to change this redirect? And also, I can access the home page, teams page etc etc, when I log in as well, but as soon as I log out, I can't access them anymore...

Comment: More specifically, I want to be all the pages accessible for guest and auth, but just the login at the bottom needs to change... That's why I'm confused with guest/auth, since it's only partially

Comment: For the logout redirect path: You can change that in your `LoginController` by changing the the [logout function](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.html#method_logout) in there.
If I understand correctly, you want everything in your `HomeController` to be accessible for both authenticated and unauthenticated users? In that case you should specify neither `guest` nor `auth` middleware.