# Laravel 5.5 auth refresh page must again login

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

Hello I have problem with Laravel Authentication (ver 5.5). This is my files:

```
HomeController.php

class HomeController extends Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index() {
        $coins = Coin::select('name')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
        return view('home.index', compact('coins'));
    }
}

web.php
Route::resource('/', 'HomeController');
Auth::routes();
```

In file `LoginController` I have `protected $redirectTo = '/';` and this same I have in `RedirectIfAuthenticated.php`:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

When I logged script redirect me to `/`. Next cookies are created:

[image]
And I am login, but

The problem is when I REFRESH page, then script redirect me to login page, and I must again legged in. If I have not provided enough details, please send me information, I edit my post.

I read this query [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47803108/laravel-5-5-login-form-on-every-page-refresh-instead-of-redirect), but not help me.

Comment: are you using the `LoginController` that already comes with Laravel?

Comment: @Wreigh Yes, file `LoginController` is created by `php artisan make:auth`

Comment: Do you have two laravel projects running concurrently?

I suspect you logging out in one, so the session is destroyed for both

The default Laravel session name was not changed

Comment: did you solve this??